# Am I getting a false positive with enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, enzyme

I'm testing a function component with enzyme, when I test it like this it actually passes the test:

```
it('should render TodoForm correctly', () => {
    const component = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <TodoItem item={item} />
      </Provider>,
    );
    expect(component.find(TodoItem)).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

But if I do this instead:

```
it('should render TodoForm correctly', () => {
    const component = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <TodoItem item={item} />
      </Provider>,
    );
    expect(component.find(TodoItem)).to.have.lengthOf(1);
  });
```

It gives me and error saying it can't read property have of undefined. I get the same error when trying to test if it has a class.

```
it('should have class marked if done is true', () => {
    const component = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <TodoItem item={item} />
      </Provider>,
    );
    expect(component.find('.marked')).to.have.lengthOf(1);
  })
```

Do I get a false positive when I test with .toBeTruthy()?

Here is my component if needed:

```
interface todoItemProps {
  item: todo
}

function TodoItem({ item }: todoItemProps) {
  const checkButtonIcon = item.done ? faRedo : faCheck;
  const checkButtonVariant = item.done ? 'warning' : 'success';
  const className = item.done ? 'marked' : '';
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  return (
    <tr>
      <td className={className}>
        {item.description}
      </td>
      <td>
        <Button onClick={() => dispatch(changeStatus(item))} variant={checkButtonVariant}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={checkButtonIcon} />
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={() => dispatch(removeTodos(item._id))} variant="danger" hidden={!item.done}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} />
        </Button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting an error while using `.to.have.` is probably because it is from a different testing library. `toBeTruthy` is from jest, and `.to.have.` is from chai. You probably didn't install chai. You don't need it, you can use the jest methods.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect

https://www.chaijs.com/

[Examples how to use enzyme with jest](https://github.com/vjwilson/enzyme-example-jest/blob/master/src/__tests__/Foo-test.js)

Comment: I tried expect(component.find(TodoItem).exists()).toBe(true) but then the test failed again.
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false

Comment: I haven't been using enzyme very long. I used it this way: instead of this `expect(component.find('.marked')).to.have.lengthOf(1);` I write this `expect(component.find('.marked').length).toBe(1);`

Comment: Look at these examples https://github.com/vjwilson/enzyme-example-jest/blob/master/src/__tests__/Foo-test.js

Comment: Doing it that way still returns Expected: 1
    Received: 0